# React Native: How to rotate view properly on orientation change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, screen-orientation

How do you properly rotate the view when the screen orientation changes in React Native?

I'm trying to display two different tables.  One in landscape mode, and one in portrait mode.  The tables change appropriately but the view doesn't rotate.

When I try to use different combinations of transform: rotate and manually setting the height/width it produces less than desirable results.

The bottom drawer navigator is also staying in the original spot on the bottom of the phone.  This makes me think that I'm going about this wrong.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated as my Google Fu is currently failing me.

Comment: add listener for screen changes, try search in google a lot of examples have

Comment: I found the problem.  I had the view locked in app.json to portrait mode.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the view locked to portrait in app.json.  When I got rid of that one line of code it worked as expected.